# Name Error when item element is added to array and controller edited at the same time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I've got a really strange problem where i Run into this particular error every time i modify my products controller

**Updated Stack Trace**

```
    Started GET "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 02:45:33 +0800
    ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
    Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms

    NameError (uninitialized constant ProductsUploader::Uploader41752080):
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `const_get'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:10:in `rescue in load_with_autoloading'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:6:in `load_with_autoloading'
  /home/kishe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/activerecord-session_store-e879bf087eb6/lib/active
_record/session_store.rb:11:in `unmarshal'
  /home/kishe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/activerecord-session_store-e879bf087eb6/lib/active
_record/session_store/session.rb:60:in `data'
  /home/kishe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/activerecord-session_store-e879bf087eb6/lib/action
_dispatch/session/active_record_store.rb:72:in `block in get_session'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:105:in `block (2 levels) in qui
etly'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:48:in `silence_stream'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:104:in `block in quietly'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:48:in `silence_stream'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:103:in `quietly'
  /home/kishe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/activerecord-session_store-e879bf087eb6/lib/action
_dispatch/session/active_record_store.rb:64:in `get_session'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `load_session'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:43:in `block in load_sess
ion'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `stale_session_chec
k!'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:43:in `load_session'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:168:in `load!'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:160:in `load_for_read!'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:86:in `[]'
  turbolinks (2.2.2) lib/turbolinks/xhr_headers.rb:35:in `set_xhr_redirected_to'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:387:in `_run__1251754324936342518__process_acti
on__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  searchkick (0.7.6) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:61:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2426553011743858253__call__callba
cks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/kishe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/kishe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/kishe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_threa
d'
  Rendered /home/kishe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/t
emplates/rescues/_source.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/kishe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/t
emplates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /home/kishe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/t
emplates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered /home/kishe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/t
emplates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (14.3ms)
```

**Update**

**This happens whenever an item is added into the session[:cart] array and the product controller is modified in any way.**

**Clearing my browser's history, cache and cookies seem to temporarily fix this too.**

I need help. I can't afford dropping my database over and over again D:

**edit - Products Controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @products = Product.all
    @category = Category.first
    end

    def create
        @product = Product.create(product_params)
        @product.category << Category.find(category_params["category_id"])
        redirect_to dashboard_product_path
    end

  def fetch_products
    @fetch = Category.find(params[:id]).products
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def add_cart
    if session[:cart].nil?
      session[:cart] = []
    end
    session[:cart] << [Product.find(params[:product]), cart_params[:Quantity]]
    flash[:notice] = "Your item has been added to the cart!"
    redirect_to products_path
  end

  def remove_cart
    remove_item = session[:cart].index(product)
    session[:cart].delete(remove_item)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render nothing: true}
    end
  end

  def moreDetailed
    @currentproduct = Product.find(params[:item])
  end

private
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image)
  end

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:category_id)
  end

  def cart_params
    params.require(:prepurchase).permit(:Quantity)
  end
end
```

**ProductUploader**

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ProductsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
   version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_fit => [300, 300]
   end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
   def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Comment: Your title says one thing, your error says another.  Can I see your Products Controller?

Comment: Just updated both titles and the product controller... not sure if the title's any more helpful than it was but I don't really know what's going on here D:

Comment: **Update -> Problem only occurs when i change something in the Products controller while an element is within session[:cart]. If the array is empty and changes are made, no problem occurs

Comment: Sorry for the extremely misleading post so far D:

Comment: What's `ProductUploader`? Could you add a few lines from the exception stack trace?

Comment: ProductUploader is a carrierwave class for defining where files are stored, the filetypes allowed, etc.